# How do I get an excel vba macro to import a document that has today's date in the title?

Tags: excel, vba, date

The document is stored in a folder called "historical", where data gets saved off every day into the folder as a new document with the day's date in the title of the document. For example, today's document would be named something like "document 08-02-19.xls". My issue is getting the macro to only pull data from the document that has today's date in it.

So far since I am not sure how to get the code to search for today's date only, I just have it pulling the file that is dated for today. I dont know how to get it to do a search for today's date and choose that one.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="DRAW", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(""K:\ALLMGE\Clearing\Wires\BMO Wires\Historic\EOD DRAWS 2019-08-01.xls"")
```

Comment: You could just concatenate the date to the filename string like `"K:\ALLMGE\Clearing\Wires\BMO Wires\Historic\EOD DRAWS " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xls"`

Comment: That code is not working for some reason. What did I do wrong? ive been playing around with it for like 2 hours now. This is exactly what I have    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(""K:\ALLMGE\Clearing\Wires\BMO Wires\Historic\EOD DRAWS " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xls"")

Comment: I don't know. It looks cool to me. When I output that string that you are concatenating together I get `Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("K:\ALLMGE\Clearing\Wires\BMO Wires\Historic\EOD DRAWS 2019-08-05.xls") ` Which I believe is what you are after. Do you get any errors?